# Is this ontology well formed?

Tags: java, ontology, owl-api, hermit

I'm trying to perform reasoners in this ontology. I post below the ontology.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
         xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
         xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
         xml:base="C:/Users/Rita/Desktop/parenthood.owl"
         xmlns="C:/Users/Rita/Desktop/parenthood.owl#">

<owl:Ontology rdf:about="C:/Users/Rita/Desktop/parenthood.owl"/>

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#has">
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Man"/>
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Son"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Man">
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
  <rdfs:comment rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">This is man</rdfs:comment>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Woman">
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
  <rdfs:comment rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">This is woman</rdfs:comment>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Son">
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Man"/>
  <rdfs:comment rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">This is son</rdfs:comment>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Daughter">
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Woman"/>
  <rdfs:comment rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">This is son</rdfs:comment>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Father">
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Man"/>
  <owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:Class>
      <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#Man"/>
        <owl:Class>
          <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <owl:Restriction>
              <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#has"/>
              <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Son"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
            <owl:Restriction>
              <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#has"/>
              <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Daughter"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
          </owl:unionOf>
        </owl:Class>
      </owl:intersectionOf>
    </owl:Class>
  </owl:equivalentClass>
  <rdfs:comment rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">This is father</rdfs:comment>
</owl:Class>

<Man rdf:about="#filippo">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual"/>
  <has rdf:resource="#matteo"/>
</Man>

<Son rdf:about="#matteo">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual"/>
</Son>


</rdf:RDF>
```

I expect the "filippo" individual to be assigned the class "father". is it right to expect that? or is the ontology bad formed? I used OWlAPI 5 and hermit as reasoner.  I'm new in ontology field!! Please help.
thanks, Rita

Comment: The rdf:about field for the ontology should not be a file path but an IRI. However the ontology looks well firmed otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not exactly answering "*is the ontology bad formed?*", however, could give some directions towards how to check for ontological adequacies and prevent a common ontological problem known as the IS-A overloading problem using the [OntoClean](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/Workshops/1999/WS-99-13/WS99-13-005.pdf) methodology [Ref](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Geert-Poels/publication/221269626_Measures_for_Assessing_Dynamic_Complexity_Aspects_of_Object-Oriented_Conceptual_Schemes/links/53f4b9ae0cf22be01c3eda9a/Measures-for-Assessing-Dynamic-Complexity-Aspects-of-Object-Oriented-Conceptual-Schemes.pdf#page=225) [Ref](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.28.7392&rep=rep1&type=pdf) [Ref](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.43.5844&rep=rep1&type=pdf) [Ref](http://www.loa.istc.cnr.it/old/Papers/CACM2002.pdf).

A common problem while developing an ontology is the IS-A overloading problem. All ontologies are centered on a taxonomy, which is a hierarchy of **classes** (eg Father) and **sub-classes** (eg. Son). These classes and sub-classes can be instantiated with **individuals** (eg.  Filippo individual assigned to the class Father, Matteo individual assigned to the class Son) and several individuals can be related using **ObjectProperty** (eg. Matteo hasFather Filippo) where hasFather is the ObjectProperty.

Meta-properties in OnoClean such as **Rigidity** and **Identity** can be used to describe the **instanceOf** relation towards developing a well-founded ontology.

> Rigidity (+R): A property P is rigid if, for each x, P(x) is true in
> one possible world, then it is also true in all possible worlds.
> Person and location are rigid, while student and tall are not.

The instanceOf link between an individual and a rigid class is described by the term rigid in OntoClean.

> Identity (+I): An identity criterion (IC) for a property is a binary
> relation Ip such that Px ^ Py ^ A Ip xy -> x=y. If, for a given
> property P, we are able to define such an Ip, then we say that P
> carries an IC for its instances.

By applying the meta-properties defined in Rigidity and Identity, it is expected to obtain a well-founded ontology which:

- Classify an entity as an instance of a Class
- Individuate an entity as a countably distinct instance of a Class